# Connecting keyboard to a audio interface

Tags: recording, audio-interfaces, keyboard

I have a Nord electro 5 keyboard and I am wanting to record using that (not as a midi).

I am just wondering what kind of audio interface to use?

I also want to be able to connect guitar and vocal to it as well. I will probably only use one instrument at a time but would be good to be able to run all three at the same time for future use.

To my understanding you don't need the keyboard to be put through an amplifier to record? And what about if I was recording some acoustic guitar would I just connect the guitar straight into it or would I need to set up a guitar mic and record it that way?

Comment: I need the model names to be able to answer this. Maybe a link to a page where they sell the model of each of these instruments you want to connect. I just need to know the specifications.

Answer (score 3):

Correct - a separate amplifier is not needed to record keyboard.
Just about any decent quality 2 channel interface will do.

For example look at the [Lexicon Alpha Studio](http://lexiconpro.com/en/products/alpha) (about $60) - on the front you have an instrument input suitable for guitar and bass, on the rear you have stereo (L and R) line in, ideal for keyboard. Moreover there is a mic input too (XLR). Seems perfect for your requirements. The interface records in 24 bit, which is important for the quality of the final mix.

You should be aware that you can only record two channels at once. It may seem like a four input channel interface telling from the number of input connectors, but actually it is only two channels - if you need to record keyboard/guitar and vocal at the same, you need to step up to something like the [Behringer UMC404HD](https://www.google.dk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiB0rCWy_TMAhWKlCwKHRBHB0YQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.music-group.com%2FCategories%2FBehringer%2FComputer-Audio%2FAudio-Interfaces%2FUMC404HD%2Fp%2FP0BK1&usg=AFQjCNG6jU9Hthnie2UC8F-nBS1yv8Oi_A&sig2=0_YTMah1ZgG94rYAWxmWKw&bvm=bv.122852650,d.bGg))

[image: Lexicon Alpha Studio - Front]
[image: Lexicon Alpha Studio - Rear]

There are many other decent models - just look for these four things:

1. Stereo In
2. Instrument In
3. XLR/Mic in
4. 24 bit recording